# Disable/Ignore Transaction Interceptor at runtime

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working on an application consisting of Spring and Hibernate frameworks. In one particular module, the application fetches the data from database (select queries). Along with the select queries, application also issues an update statement. After further debugging, I found that the update query is fired from some TransactionInterceptor.
I think, transaction interceptor is not required here as all are select queries. Can anyone please suggest me a way to disable/suppress this interceptor at runtime?

This problem might sound too abstract at first. However, I am new to this application and don't have much knowledge about it's architecture. If you need any configuration details, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hibernate doesn't execute update statements because a transaction exists. It executes them because you modified an entity. If you don't want an update statement to be executed, don't modify any entity. Transactions are necessary, even for read-only use-cases.

Comment: I haven't modified any entity. I am clicking on a link which just fetches the list from db. Besides that, it also updates the user table. I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to suppress the update query by writing the following line in my DAO class (which was extending HibernateDAOSupport)

`super.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().clear();`

I just cleared the session as there was no update required while fetching the data and interceptor was updating the table.

Also, the original issue which I was facing is, the application was encountering `org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update: 0 actual row count: 0 expected: 1` from this update statement when it got executed twice (God knows why!).

Hence, we figured out that the update was never required and wanted to suppress it.

Can this fix have any consequences on the application? Is this the right way to do it? Will appreciate the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your application-context.xml transaction management declarations part. Where the bean : `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager` is defined.

If the annotaion is not enabled you should activate it like this :

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="yourDataSource" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
```

Comment: Here are the mappings for TransactionManager:

`<bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory">
        </property>
    </bean>

 <bean id="transactionInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">
        <property name="transactionAttributeSource" ref="transactionAttributeSource">
        </property>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager">
        </property>
    </bean>`

Answer (score 1):

`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)`
on your method will disable any Spring transactions on this proxy method call. Note that by disabling the transaction you also lose other benefits, like isolation.

However, the fact that you have an update query fired is NOT because of a transaction. You are likely to encounter a different error if you simply remove the transaction (likely stale object exception when hibernate tries to update outside of a transaction, or a malfunction of some module). Hibernate does not fire spurious updates, you should look for updates to the object in question during your transaction.

Comment: I don't want to remove the transaction. I just want to disable/remove the interceptors around it.

Comment: @DarshanMehta A transaction interceptor is the spring component that creates and manages the transactions. How do you think you will remove the creator of transactions without removing transactions?

Comment: Unless, of course, you have added your own custom transaction interceptors. In which case you should be able to decide when they can act anyway.

Comment: If I particularly want to disable this interceptor, that too, in a specific condition then, is it possible programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have the JavaDoc of the interface `org.hibernate.Session` method `clear()` :

*Completely clear the session. Evict all loaded instances and cancel all pending saves, updates and deletions. Do not close open iterators or instances of* `ScrollableResults`

So when you use clear you will clear whole the Session. That ok, you will ask me : have I only one session per transaction ? I will answer you it's depends on your application `HibernateTemplate` configuration, if the `HibernateTemplate.alwaysUseNewSession==true` but the default value is `false`. The solution is to not intercepte your dao method with the Transaction Manager because it will be executed by default in a non Transactional Session.

Did you get a look to the [Spring Framework AOP Proxy configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html). section `10.5 Declarative transaction management`

Answer (score 0):

So your `PlatformTransactionManager` instance is `HibernateTransactionManager`. `TransactionInterceptor` will delegate the transaction handling to `HibernateTransactionManager`. All that means : all calls that you make to your data access methods annotated with `@Transactional` will be path throw spring AOP Proxy (which is a Proxy Design pattern).
If you don't use annotation-based and you have declared an AOP Proxy (search for aop:config tag in your ApplicationContext.xml).
So in the AOP Proxy configuration you will find the politic that your application use for intercepting data access methods and handling transactions.
For finding if you are using annotation-based you should know what is 'transactionAttributeSource' : AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource or AttributesTransactionAttributeSource ?

Comment: Is is possible to disable interceptor programmatically? Or, is it possible to get the list of interceptors which are associated with the current transaction?

Comment: Yo can do what ever you want as it an AOP Proxy you can define your self your politic of transaction handling but you should know what your application is using Annotation-based or Attributes-based.

Comment: My application is not using any annotation. Also, can you please provide an example or two of how to disable interceptor programmatically? I do not want to alter any configuration. I just want to disable the interceptor in a particular condition at runtime.

Comment: @ red1kissi I managed to solve it by clearing the session. Please see my answer below. Does this solution seem appropriate to you?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only select queries in a method you can use readOnly attribute in @Transactional annotation (@Transactional(readOnly = true)). It will be used by Spring to optimize the underlying data access layer operations (such as hibernate's "dirty" checking) and improve a perfomance. If your entity is never changes @org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable is another solution. But update statement doesn't appear without changes in entity state, so you should check your code for persistent entity changes.
I am agreed that disable transaction interceptor is not a good solution.